# Center Input box and Font Awesome icons

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

Others have asked something similar but I seem to be struggling vertical aligning the font awesome icon with an input box.  It works okay when you don`t use the sizing to increase the font awesome icons, but as soon as you enter the fa-3x or something like that the margin-top gets added.

Does anybody have any ideas ?

Simple example would be:

```
<div>
    <i class='icon icon-3x icon-camera'></i>
    <span id="inputfield">
      <input type="text" value="input here">
    </span>
</div>

div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
i{
    float: left;
}
#inputfield{
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Easy fix. Remove fa-3x. set font-size:35px or 3 times normal for i.fa-camera{}

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></legend>
<input type="text" class="something">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is magic, Flexbox is our savior.

```css
div{
   border : blue dashed 1px;
   display : flex;
   align-items : center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-camera-128.png"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="input here">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

can be achived with this
html

```
<div class="input-group">
    <i class='fa fa-3x fa-camera'></i>
      <input type="text" value="input here">
</div>
```

css

```
div.input-group
{
  display:table;
  margin:30px;
}

.input-group > input[type=text],
.input-group > i.fa
{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.input-group > i.fa
{
  line-height:20px;
}
```

here is link for reference [codepen link](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/dRoEpr)

i have added margin to div element to make it visible.

hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `class fa-3x` and give font size to the `<i>` or rather the curresponding class

find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/2099/)

```
<div>
    <i class='fa fa-camera'></i>
    <span id="inputfield">
      <input type="text" value="input here">
    </span>
</div>

div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
i{
    float: left;
}
i.fa-camera{
  font-size:35px;
}
#inputfield{
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A(nother) flexbox solution

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#inputfield {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#inputfield::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 48px;
  content: "\f030";
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div id="inputfield">
    <input type="text" value="input here">
  </div>
</div>
```